# How to get output_attentions of a pretrained Distilbert Model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tf.keras, huggingface-transformers, distilbert

I am using a pretrained DistilBert model:

```
from transformers import TFDistilBertModel,DistilBertConfig

dbert = 'distilbert-base-uncased'

config = DistilBertConfig(max_position_embeddings=256 , dropout=0.2, 
                          attention_dropout=0.2, 
                          output_hidden_states=True,
                          output_attentions=True) #or true

dbert_model = TFDistilBertModel.from_pretrained(dbert, config)

input_ids_in = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(256,), name='input_id', dtype='int32')
input_masks_in = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(256,), name='attn_mask', dtype='int32') 

outputs = dbert_model([input_ids_in, input_masks_in], output_attentions = 1)
```

I am trying to get the output_attentions. But the output is of length 1 and is given as:

> TFBaseModelOutput([('last_hidden_state',
> <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 256, 768) dtype=float32 (created by layer 'tf_distil_bert_model_6')>)])

i have given "output_attentions = True" in config and in forward pass "output_attentions = 1" is specified. Can anyone let me know what i am doing wrong?
EDIT:
I have changed the default configuration value of `max_positional_embeddings`  of 512 to 256. if i change my model instantiation to

```
dbert_model = TFDistilBertModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased',config=config)
```

it gives me the following error.

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 393216 into shape (256,768)
```

768*512 being 393216. So it might be related to config code.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know much about Keras, but `tf.keras.layers.Input` seems to be different from what the tokenizer returns (`tf.Tensor`). It works as expected with the tokenizer input. Maybe that helps you a bit.

Comment: @cronoik Actually  `tf.keras.layers.input` represents symbolic tensors. As far as i understood tokenizer returns `tf.tensors`. So will it make any difference. input_ids_in gives `KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 256), dtype=tf.int32, name='input_id'), name='input_id', description="created by layer 'input_id'")`

Comment: I got the solution to anyone looking: modified the code as ` dbert_model = TFDistilBertModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased',config, output_attentions=True)`   This gave both hidden states and attention in output.

Comment: Please submit it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the answer as @cronoik suggested: I modified the code as  `dbert_model = TFDistilBertModel.from_pretrained('distilbert-base-uncased',config, output_attentions=True)` This gave both hidden states and attention in output.